# Does spectral normalization preserve eigenvalue ratios?

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, eigenvalues-eigenvectors

Let $A$ be a non-negative square matrix. Normalize $A$ by its spectral radius $\sigma(A)$, and call it $A_2 = A/\sigma(A)$. Does this normalization preserve the ratio between the two largest eigenvalues of $A$? That is, is the ratio $\lambda_1/\lambda_2$ the same for $A$ and $A_2$, where $\lambda_1$ and $\lambda_2$ are the absolute values of the first and second largest eigenvalues of the two matrices?

Answer (score 1):

Of course. If $\lambda_1,\ldots,\lambda_n$ are the eigenvalues of $A$, then the eigenvalues of $\alpha A$ are $\alpha\lambda_1,\ldots,\alpha\lambda_n$.

This can be easily seen via de Schur decomposition.

Comment: Schurly you don't need anything so fancy: if $A v = \lambda v$, then $\alpha A v = \alpha \lambda v$.

Comment: Good point. I guess I don't think often enough about finite dimension...